# How to add wiredTiger in pymongo at collection level?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, zlib, wiredtiger

I'm trying to enable data compression in MongoDB 3.0 using the wiredTiger engine. The compression works fine at the server level where I can provide a global compression algorithm for all the collections in the mongo server config file like this:

```
storage:
  engine: wiredTiger
  wiredTiger:
    collectionConfig:
      blockCompressor: zlib
```

I want to enable this compression at collection level which can be done by using the below code in mongodb shell:

```
db.createCollection( "test", {storageEngine:{wiredTiger:{configString:'block_compressor=zlib'}}} );
```

How can I do this using the pymongo driver ?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient("localhost:27017")
db = client.mydb
```

Comment: have you tried `db.create_collection('test', storageEngine={'configString':'block_compressor=zlib'})` ?

Comment: Yup. It works as I've mentioned in the question. I want to do the same thing using pymongo and not the mongo shell.

Comment: the code I wrote is python code for the pymongo driver. See [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.create_collection)

Comment: Thanks it worked. Didn't saw the `create_collection` method before. Sorry for the confusion. `db.create_collection('test', storageEngine={'wiredTiger':{'configString':'block_compressor=zlib'}})`

Comment: yep, it did look a bit weird as a parameter. And I wrote part of it as well, sorry. I have added it as an answer, please accept it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given it works via the Mongo shell, pass the same parameters via pymongo:

```
db.create_collection('test',
                     storageEngine={'wiredTiger':{'configString':'block_compressor=zlib'}})
```

from the [official docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.create_collection) we see that

> create_collection(name, codec_options=None, read_preference=None,
> write_concern=None, read_concern=None, **kwargs)
>
> ...
>
> **kwargs (optional): additional keyword arguments will be passed as options for the create collection command

Comment: how do you check which storage engine is being used via pymongo?

Comment: @vgoklani you can check it directly in the mongo shell by using `db.test.stats()` it should show a `wiredTiger` output. [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/#basic-stats-lookup)